# In JavaFX, Attribute for layout to change its height and width with stage

Tags: javafx

I have created Scene in SceneBuilder and want a attribute that will change sub-layout's height and width with parent's. I have done it using binding in controller class. But this is time consuming to apply binding to each and every sub-layout and controller. So I want an attribute or combination of attributes that with help me to save time and effort in coding. I have a simple example that may help you to answer my question, where I just put HBox inside VBox.

When I designed it in SceneBuilder:

[image]

And When I make it Full-Screen:

[image]

Comment: "*I have a simple example that may help you to answer my question, where I just put HBox inside VBox.*" Why is that example not posted in the question?

Comment: Because my question was not specific for vbox and hbox combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the parent layout. There's no general way of doing it this for every possible layout.

For `VBox` you should use `VBox.vgrow` (setting it to `Priority.SOMETIMES` for all children) and `VBox`'s `fillWidth` property but you cannot achieve this for `Pane`, for `AnchorPane` it would require you to set the anchors, for `GridPane` column/row constraints with `percentWidth`/`percentHeight` or grow priorities could be used...

#### Example for `VBox`/`HBox`

```xml
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
   <children>
      <HBox style="-fx-background-color: green;" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <HBox style="-fx-background-color: blue;" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <HBox style="-fx-background-color: red;" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

#### Alternative way of creating bindings

You can use expression binding to create some of the bindings. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding

```xml
<VBox fx:id="vbox" fillWidth="false" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="${vbox.width * 0.5}" />
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="${vbox.width * 0.5}" />
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" prefWidth="${vbox.width * 0.5}" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Note that SceneBuilder will show warnings and not properly display the preview, if you use this approach.